# How do i prove that condition 2 does not implies condition 1?

Tags: logic, proof-writing

im having a hard time trying with this prove. Im very new with this type of proves so please be patient.
We have this.

Condition 1: if $x∈C(A)$ and $C(B)∩A ≠ ∅, $ then $x ∈ C(A∪B). $

Condition 2: if  $x ∈ C(A)$ and $x ∈ C(B)$, then $x ∈ C(A∪B)$

we must give a counterexample:

Im not really sure how to start this. So what part of the axiom do you take as given? (do you need to take both parts of the Axiom 1 as given?) and what part of the axiom do you need to contradict? (do you have to contradict this part of Axiom 2: $x ∈ C(A)$ and $x ∈ C(B)$ or this part: $ $x ∈ C(A∪B).

And please be patient. I really tried to find similar problmes before posting here, but i think i need a more detailed answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does $C(A)$ mean?  Compliment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure axiom of choice is not the correct tag.

Comment: Are "condition 1" and "axiom 1" the same thing? If not, please list these axioms you're referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition 1 takes on the form: $(p\land q)\rightarrow r$ where $\land$ represents "and" and $\rightarrow$ represents material implication. An implication is false only when the antecedent (first bit) is true and the consequent (second bit) is false. In this case, we need $p\land q$ to hold but $r$ to not hold. $p\land q$ holds when both $p$ holds and $q$ holds, by definition. Putting this all together, we have that condition 1 fails to hold only when $p$ and $q$ are satisfied and $r$ is not. Concretely, this would mean that $x\in C(A)$ and $C(B)\cap A\neq \emptyset$ hold, but $x\in C(A\cup B)$ doesn't hold. Under all other situations, Condition 1 holds.

Condition 2 takes on the same logical form, and the same analysis applies. It holds in every case except when $x\in C(A)$ and $x\in C(B)$ both hold, but $x\in C(A\cup B)$ doesn't hold.

The statement "Condition 1 implies Condition 2" has the logical form $p\rightarrow q$. This fails to hold precisely when $q$ doesn't hold but $p$ does hold.

Now let's look at the these three facts together. From the fact that Condition 1 fails to hold you need an example where $x\in C(A)$ holds and $C(B)\cap A\neq\emptyset$ holds but $x\in C(A\cup B)$ doesn't. You also need that Condition 2 holds. Since we've already decided that $x\in C(A\cup B)$ doesn't hold, we would need that at least one of $x\in C(A)$ and $x\in C(B)$ doesn't hold (as otherwise Condition 2 wouldn't hold). We've also already decided that $x\in C(A)$ holds, so it must be that $x\in C(B)$ is the one that doesn't hold.

Succinctly, you need to give an example where $x\in C(A),x\notin C(B), C(B)\cap A\neq\emptyset,$ and $x\notin C(A\cup B)$.

Comment: That was a very good explanation. Can you tell me if this example is right? X = {x, y, z}. Taking  A = {x, y} and B = {y, z}. We have that z∈C(xyz) x∈C(xy), z∈C(xy) y∈C(yz)

Comment: @neto333 I'm glad the explination made sense. I'm not sure if that's a good example because I don't really understand the problem. What does $C(A)$ mean? When you type $C(xyz)$ do you mean $C(X)=C(\{x,y,z\})$?

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, Venn Diagrams.

But I'm not going to make one (graphics are difficult).  So I'll describe 1:

You have an image with $4$ distinct commponent's

$X = (A\cup B)^c = $ every thing that is in neither $A$ nor $B$.  The "outside".

$Y = (A \setminus B) = $ every thing in $A$ but not $B$.  The "unique to $A$".  part.

$Z = (B \setminus A) = $ everything in $B$ but not in $A$.

$W = A \cap B$.  Everything in $B$ and in $A$.

Let's fill these up with elements to make a bland boring system.

Let's put $1$ in $X$.  i.e. neither $A$ nor $B$ have $1$.

Let's put $2$ in $Y$. i.e. $A$ has $2$ but $B$ does not.

Let's put $3$ in $Z$. i.e $A$ and $B$ both have $3$.

And put $4$ in $W$. i.e. $B$ has $4$ but $A$ does not.

So $A = \{2,3\}; B= \{3,4\}$ and $U = \{1,2,3,4\}$.

This is a basic boring class of sets.

1) Says: $x \in A^c$.  So $x = \{1,4\}$ and $B^c \cap A = \{2\}$ is not empty.  This would imply $x \in (A\cup B)^c = \{1\}$.

In this case, that would mean $4$ can not exist and nothing can be in $B \setminus A$.  That would mean $B \subset A$.

That's all 1) is describing. 1) = "$B\subset A$ and $B^c \cap A = A \setminus B $ is not empty" or $B \subsetneq A$.

2) Says: $x \in A^c$.  So $x = \{1,4\}$.  And $x \in B^c =\{1,2\}$ so $x \in A^c \cap B^c = (A\cup B)^c = \{1\}$.  If that is the case then $x \in (A\cup B)^c= \{1\}$.

Um... this is *always* true.

So 1) = "$B\subsetneq A$" and 2) "$A$ and $B$ are sets" (or any obvious always true statement).

So a counter example would be any sets $A$ and $B$ where $B \not \subset A$.

Our example where $A = \{2,3\}$ and $B = \{3,4\}$ is a fine counter example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Sorry for the confusion between C and compliment. Still helps me to understand how to prove this type of things so thank you :).

Comment: It may help to get fluent with laws such as $(A \cup B)^c = A^c\cap B^c$.  That what make statement 2) clearly a tautology.  $x\in A^c$ and $x\in B^c$ means $x \in A^c \cap B^c = (A\cup B)^c$. Always true. Likewise $(A\cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c\subset A^c;A^c=(A\cup B)^c \cup B\setminus A$ would tell you that $x\in A^c\supset (A\cup B)^c\implies x\in (A\cup B)^c$ would mean $B\setminus A=\emptyset\implies B\subset A$.